# How to detect a blank line between filled lines in .txt file and convert it to a single tab

Tags: bash, macos

I an running a bash/.dat script (Mac terminal) and part of it is converting each line return into  a TAB (to get it ready for nicely importing into Excel). The problem is that I also want to remove all extra blank lines *except* a single blank line when comes *between* two filled lines. So...

```
Line pre-A is blank
Line A has text
Line B has text 
Line C is blank
Line D has text
Line E is blank
Line F is blank
```

Line C above would become a TAB and Line E and F (and pre-A) would be deleted. Also, sometimes there is a blank line before Line A (labelled Line pre-A above), so I'd want it removed but not replaced with a TAB.

So the result would be:

```
Line A text [TAB] Line B text [TAB] [TAB] Line D text
```

...and it'd be OK if Line D text was followed by a [TAB]. Make sense? Is this doable and, if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` is your option, would you please try:

```
perl -0777pe 's/^\n+//; s/\n{3,}/\t/g; s/\n/\t/g' file.txt
```

- The `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp all lines at once to process
  newline characters between lines.
- The `-pe` option enables the one-liner programming.
- The first substitution `s/^\n+//` removes the pre blank line(s).
- The next `s/\n{3,}/\t/g` converts three or more consecutive newline
  characters (meaning two or more blank lines) into a tab character.
- The last `s/\n/\t/g` converts the newline characters into the same number
  of tab characters.